# Extracting values from XML file using xslt

Tags: xml, linux, xslt

I need to extract some values from the following xml file.

```
<PAIR symbol="sym1">
        <value-date row="0" name="TOM" date="2014-05-15"/>
        <value-date row="0" name="SP" date="2014-05-16"/>
<PAIR>
```

I have to print like this:

`sym1 2014-05-15
sym1 2014-05-16`

I used the following cmnd in linux to do this:
`xsltproc a.xslt xmlfilename`

My `a.xslt` is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//PAIR">
"<xsl:value-of select="@symbol"/>"
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="value-date">
"<xsl:value-of select="@date"/>"
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is extracting the symbol only. Not extracting the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your `a.xslt` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="PAIR/value-date">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@symbol"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```